# Improve Alexa rating with requests

Tags: android, httpclient, alexa-internet

I have a site and android app of it and many users are using my site's app.
In my app i use `HttpPost`, `HttpGet` and `HttpClient` for sending request to my server.

My question is how can i tell Alexa in every request that a user visited my site and uses its services.

Comment: Hi Sepehr. Have you found your answer? could you please share it to others? thansk

Comment: Hello @VahidGhadiri. unfortunately no, I haven't find my answer yet. and AFAIK it is nearly impossible to do that.